# Triage Dispute Audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, triage

As usual, I'm contributing on daily manner to Stack Overflow community, and I've just failed on this review audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21897504

I disagree with it because:

- there is NO [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !
- there is one little writing mistake to fix (an useless 'a')
- the source code formatting is unclear
- (less important, but still interesting to improve the question quality) some parts should be put in bold

Could you update this review audit, and allow me to keep on contributing?

Comment: all of these points means a good edit by the OP salvages the question though.... isn't the purpose of that queue to make sure questions that have a chance at being good are kept open?

Comment: Note: whatever you happen to think about any given [tag:perl6] question, people following that tag *love* each and every one of them.

Comment: @Patrice without diving into details of this particular audit, your approach looks like in a contradiction with [general consensus on meta laid out here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/839601): if only edits from OP can salvage question then it should be triaged for closure. Requires editing is reserved only if salvaging edits can be done by folks other than OP

Comment: @gnat wasn't it the other way around?! I feel like that was the main issue of the queue at first (or am I going senile and inverting the scenario? Or, better: Stack fixed the issue with the queue and I am remembering how it used to be)....

Comment: @Patrice requires editing pushes the post to the help and improvement queue where users from the community are expected to edit questions into shape. If an edit from the OP is required then requires editing is the wrong reason to choose.

Comment: I think the source code formatting is very clear, considering it's REPL code including output. If it wasn't REPL it would've been easier to have copy-pastable code and output separately, but it's REPL-specific behaviour, so not much to do about it.

Comment: @TinyGiant fair enough.... then I am misremembering something somewhere I guess. Anyway thx for the clarification there

Comment: @Patrice that said, the assertion that the question is missing information required to answer is incorrect, so you're right in that the remaining errors would justify a requires editing review.

Comment: Thanks everyone for clarification (I'm surprised to get so much feedback). I'm still confused because this question doesn't look like I use to see a good question, but maybe it is because it is about REPL code, I don't master; I should have skip :/

Comment: @PaulCrovella Gosh, people do upvote [tag:perl6] questions like crazy!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two contexts available to a reviewer when performing a review.

- Generic; does the question look like it *could* be a question here with all of the correct parts in it?
- Specific; does the question in context to the problem domain make coherent sense?

Sometimes when reviewing, you require both contexts.  If the question satisfies the generic context but you're not quite certain on the specific front, it may be safest to simply skip the question and leave it for someone else who is more experienced.

To your points:

> - there is NO [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

The question explicitly shows REPL output *alongside* an error message.  This more than satisfies MCVE.

> - there is writing mistakes to fix

**Fix** them.  This isn't a reason to close a question; it's an opportunity for *you* to make an improvement to the question.

> - the source code formatting is unclear

This goes back to the "Specific" context; given that you probably wouldn't recognize this as REPL output, it is easy to see how one could fall into this trap.

> - (less important, but still interesting to improve the question quality) some parts should be put in bold

You originally had `<strong>` tags, which in HTML parlance would translate to **bold** text.  I disagree.  Nothing in that question needs to be emboldened.

Comment: Perl version like `Perl 6.c`, Rakudo and MoarVM may be interesting to be emboldened no?  ("nice to have", not "need").

Comment: Not sure why.  They're not points of emphasis.

Comment: To make the question read easier?

Comment: The more bold text a piece of work has, the *less* readable it becomes.  Using formatting sparingly and only when absolutely necessary to add emphasis or meaning is appropriate.  I see how the question could become *less* readable if that were emboldened.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer ... morality, I should have skipped this question, because I don't know REPL code. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 10):

I think it is a good question.

They are asking about a specific version of the language, in a specific context (the repl) and show code that triggers their issue. They say what they are expecting to happen, and how it correctly happens.

Everything is there for a quality question.

In any event, the points you mention - formatting, language errors - can easily be edited, which makes "unsalvageable" an obviously wrong choice. It most definitely *is* salvageable, given we even agree that there's a problem with it...